# I waited there for five minutes; that seemed so many hours to me

Tags: singular-vs-plural, comparative-constructions

I am supposed to correct this sentence:

> I waited there for five minutes; that seemed so many hours to me.

The answer in the book says:

> that seemed as many hour to me.

I think this is plainly wrong. First, it should still be "hours" and not "hour." Also, "seem as" sounds weird to me. Any suggestions? How about replacing it with "seemed like" or "seemed many hours"?

Comment: This does seem plainly wrong. It's probably a typo in the book. I think your book is a grammar book, and this does seem like a horrible mistake for a grammar book to make...

Comment: "that seemed *like* (so) many hours to me" would be more natural. What is the book? Does it give any explanation for their answer? If not, get another book.

Comment: *seemed as* is correct, although it's a rather poetic phrasing.  *hour* is definitely incorrect, though.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence intended to say that the 5 minute wait felt like 5 hours.

As above there may be a typo in the book answer and it should read "I waited for 5 minutes; that seemed as many hours to me"

This is not a typical way of speaking English however is encountered in written English in books/novels etc to avoid repetition.

When talking we're more likely to say "I waited for 5 minutes, it seemed like 5 hours" with an emphasis on "hours"....

Comment: Welcome to English SE! I don't really see where it says it felt like specifically 5 hours...? Am I missing something?